# Debugging EF Navigation properties yields "ExecuteReader requires and open and available Connection. The connection’s current state is closed."

Tags: entity-framework, debugging

When you are debugging and EF entities that have navigation properties that haven’t loaded because of lazy loading, you would normally get something like this in the debugger window:

```
The function evaluation requires all threads to run
```

Then when you click on the little thread icon, it evaluates this by executing a query to the database and you get something like this:

[Navigation Property Expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/es94M.png)

Occasionally you will get an exception when you try to evaluate the property:

[Exception when navigating property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pF0SF.png)

The full stack trace:

ExecuteReader requires and open and available Connection. The connection’s current state is closed.
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__6()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.Execute(MergeOption mergeOption)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference`1.Load(MergeOption mergeOption)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.Load()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.DeferredLoad()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.LazyLoadBehavior.LoadProperty[TItem](TItem propertyValue, String relationshipName, String targetRoleName, Boolean mustBeNull, Object wrapperObject)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.LazyLoadBehavior.<>c__DisplayClass7`2.b__2(TProxy proxy, TItem item)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.NameOfProperty_819B7CF59ACBFAC0FE367DDDFF9720DFDEDAB294A8AEAD37D4460065346EAF5F.get_LatestVersion()

Notes:

-The issue only ever occurs when debugging and a Navigation property is expanded.  The issue never occurs under normal code execution or on a production environment

-The problem is found in all versions of EF 6.0.x up to the latest 6.1.3

-All developers report this problem as something that has started occurring in recent history although there is no pattern that can be found as the problem happens on a variety of configurations of Windows 8, 10, Visual Studio 2013, 2015 with various different updates

-Once the error occurs, any access to the EF context is hampered with errors

-The error may not occur during the first couple of HTTP requests of a debugging session

-The error is nothing to do with the DI container as the error is seen on Unity, Autofac and without any DI implemented for the EF context

-Implementing an interceptor seems to alter the underlying code path so the error doesn’t occur

Workarounds:

Implementing an interceptor will prevent the error from happening. The easiest way of doing this is to use the EF Logging interceptor (Database.Log). This can be set up in the Entity Context’s constructor and can be done by passing in an empty func.  We wrap it in an “#if..debug” to make sure it only executes in the debug local environment to save performance:

```
public EntityContext()
{
   #if DEBUG
        Database.Log = s => { };
   #endif
}
```

Comment: Let me guess: you have some kind of repository that wraps Entity Framework, and your DbContext goes out of scope?

Comment: In some examples yes, but I've also tried newing up a DbContext completely independent of the repository pattern and the issue still persists.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? We are encountering exactly the same issues but your workaround doesn't work for us :( EF is kind of unusable like this...

Comment: No solution for this. sorry